# iOS/ Android app folder structure for React-Native app

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm creating a React-native app which I'll integrate into iOS/Android app(already created). Can you please suggest a good way of folder structure(especially React-Native).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really like this way to structure an Project:

```
── app
   ├── components
   ├── config
   ├── index.js
   ├── lib
   └── screens
```

More Information about this, you find here: 
https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/organizing-a-react-native-project-9514dfadaa0

Comment: This suggestion is for a new app, I need it for already created app in iOS and Android

Comment: You can use this structure when ever you want. /app goes on the same level like your /android and /ios Directory and contain all your react-native app data.

Comment: If react-native app 2000 + components, so that case which folder structure is best?